# Use OR in Regex Expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex to match the following:

```
somedomain.com/services/something
```

Basically I need to ensure that /services is present.

The regex I am using and which is working is:

```
\/services*
```

But I need to match `/services` OR `/servicos`. I tried the following:

```
(\/services|\/servicos)*
```

But this shows 24 matches?! https://regex101.com/r/jvB1lr/1

How to create this regex?

Comment: Did you have a chance to read my answer? I wonder what you actually want to do. Maybe `/servic[eo]s(?=/|$)` will work best for you.

Answer (score 2):

The `(\/services|\/servicos)*` matches 0+ occurrences of `/services` or `/servicos`, and that means it can match an empty string anywhere inside the input string.

You can group the alternatives like `/(services|servicos)` and remove the `*` quantifier, but for this case, it is much better to use a character class `[oe]` as the strings only differ in 1 char.

You want to use  the following pattern:

```
/servic[eo]s
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vzRQap/1)

To make sure you match a whole subpart, you may append `(?:/|$)` at the pattern end, `/servic[eo]s(?:/|$)`.

In C#, you may use `Regex.IsMatch` with the pattern to see if there is a match in a string:

```
var isFound = Regex.IsMatch(s, @"/servic[eo]s(?:/|$)");
```

Note that you do not need to escape `/` in a .NET regex as it is not a special regex metacharacter.

**Pattern details**

- `/` - a `/`
- `servic[eo]s` - `services` or `servicos`
- `(?:/|$)` - `/` or end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Well the `*` quantifier means zero or more, so that is the problem. Remove that and it should work fine:

```
(\/services|\/servicos)
```

Keep in mind that in your example, you have a typo in the URL so it will correctly not match anything as it stands.

[Here is an example](https://regex101.com/r/WTENMH/1) with the typo in the URL fixed, so it shows 1 match as expected.

Answer (score 0):

First off you specify C# (really .Net is the library which holds regex not the language) in this post but regex101 in your example is set to PHP. That is providing you with invalid information such as needed to escape a forward slash `/` with `\/` which is unnecessary in .Net regular expressions. The regex language is the same but there are different tools which behave differently and php is not like .Net regex.

---

Secondly the star `*` on the `( )` is saying that there may be **nothing** in the parenthesis and your match is getting *null* nothing matches on every word.

---

Thirdly one does not need to split the whole word. I would just extract the commonality in the words into a set `[ ]`. That will allow the "or-ness" you need to match on either services or servicos. Such as

`(/servic[oe]s)`

Will inform you if services are found or not. Nothing else is needed.